# Pandas - Get two digit year out of a date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a date column in a pandas DataFrame which shows the date that the future contract expires. I need to use that information to create a new column with a name that my back tester accepts. The format I need it in is:

```
metadata['backtester_name'] = 'NF' + month_code + 2_digit_year
```

I know how to get the month_code, I need help to figure out how to get the 2_digit_year for this column.

This is what the expiry column looks like, it's formatted as an object by default:

```
expiry
2009-01-29
2010-01-28
2011-01-27
```

This is the formula that I'm playing around with:

```
metadata['backtesting_name'] = 'NF' + pd.DatetimeIndex(metadata['expiry']).month.map(month_code) + str(pd.to_datetime(metadata['expiry']))[2:]
```

My issue is that the year is not getting captured correctly, it returns some kind of series:

```
backtesting_name
0    NFF0     2009-01-29\n1     2010-01-28\n2     2...
1    NFF0     2009-01-29\n1     2010-01-28\n2     2...
2    NFF0     2009-01-29\n1     2010-01-28\n2     2...
3    NFF0     2009-01-29\n1     2010-01-28\n2     2...
4    NFF0     2009-01-29\n1     2010-01-28\n2     2...
```

Your help would be appreciated, let me know if I need to share any other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with `%y` for `YY` format, also is possible create helper varaible for Series of datetimes and reuse it:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(metadata['expiry'])
metadata['backtesting_name'] = 'NF' + dates.month.map(month_code) + dates.dt.strftime('%y')
```